# How to execute an expression?

Tags: python, ironpython

How to execute given expression in python? Please help me with an example.

```
a = '' 
c = 'IF(Value(a)<>"", Value(a))'
```

Comment: What is an Expression? what are you trying to do?

Comment: For starters, the expression has to be written in valid Python syntax.

Comment: Actually, I am checking IronPython code which mentioned in the query. I little bit confused that they passing this expression variable into NamedValueBag dictionary like namedValueBag.Add("Expression", ExpressionVariable). So expression Is Python code or C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval()` to evaluate string into expression as shown in following example.

```
a = '' 
c = '(a <> a)'

print eval(c)
```

**output:**

```
False
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to check if `a` is not empty, you can write:

```
a != ''
```

To assign the result to `c`:

```
>>> a = ''
>>> c = a != ''
>>> c
False
```

Actually, an empty string is falsey in python and every other string is truthy. It means you could simply set `c` to `a` and use `c` as a boolean:

```
>>> c = a
>>> if not c:
...     print("a is empty!")
... 
a is empty!
```

Comment: Actually, I am checking IronPython code which mentioned in the query. I little bit confused that they passing this expression variable into NamedValueBag dictionary like namedValueBag.Add("Expression", ExpressionVariable). So expression Is Python code or C#?